How to show "— "character
I have a document which is not showing the "—" character. This is the header.


\documentclass[letterpaper, 12pt]{article}
%\usepackage[letterpaper,margin=1.75in,noheadfoot]{geometry}
\usepackage[margin=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{fontspec, color, enumerate, sectsty}


\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % Required for inputting international characters
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % Output font encoding for international characters

\usepackage[skip=7pt, indent=1.5cm]{parskip}

%% FONTS SETUP
%\usepackage[sc]{mathpazo} % also looks good
\usepackage{mathptmx} % Use Times
\usepackage{microtype} % Idk why it is here. Slightly tweak font spacing for aesthetics
\linespread{1.1} % Increase line spacing slightly


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%                      YOUR INFORMATION
%
%      PLEASE EDIT THE FOLLOWING LINES ACCORDINGLY!!
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newcommand{\soptitle}{Statement of Purpose
\normalsize
\\Stanford University
\\Doctor of Musical Arts
\\}
\newcommand{\yourname}{My name}
\newcommand{\youremail}{my email@gmail.com}

\usepackage[bookmarks, colorlinks, breaklinks,
pdftitle={\yourname - \soptitle},pdfauthor={\yourname}, unicode]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{linkcolor=magneta,citecolor=magenta,filecolor=magenta,urlcolor=[named]{WildStrawberry}}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%                      Title and Author Name
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}
\begin{center}{\huge \scshape \soptitle}\end{center}
\begin{center}\vspace{0.2em} {\Large \yourname\\}
  {\youremail}\end{center}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%                      SOP Body
% NOTE: Use \amper instead of \&

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


Pellentesque ut neque augue. Suspendisse id dictum felis. Proin at cursus mi. Ut venenatis massa urna, sed lobortis ligula lacinia at. Ut eu eros id nibh suscipit congue. Nunc suscipit leo a libero tristique, nec pharetra ex accumsan. Etiam quis eleifend libero, at volutpat elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus pretium orci a luctus pellentesque. In at placerat ligula, vel tincidunt lorem. Nam quis sapien fringilla quam tempus tempus quis faucibus quam. Integer vestibulum eget ante sed commodo. Aliquam nisl nunc, congue ut suscipit in, lacinia sit amet est. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos.
\end{document}

I noticed that omiting inputenc and fontenc, I can use the character in question. But the font is not loaded.
I noticed that using \usepackage{newtx} fix this problem, however, it also changes a bit the style of the font, idk specifically what is different, if anyone can clarify if is possible to maintain the font boldish look and the character. Example :
without newtx

with newtx

I am a bit new, sorry the newb question.

Please extend you code to a full minimal example. That makes it easier to test.

You have loaded fontspec so must be using latex or xetex, so never use fontenc or inputenc which set up legacy encoding having and do not use 8 bit  font packages such as mathptx,  even with pdflatex mathptx is very old and not recommended for any new document. You can use fontsoec to load TeX Gyre Termes  for a times Roman clone font

I updated with the entire code.
Hmm yeah. Using fontspec fix that, however the font looks different.
what command should I use to load TeX Gyre Termes

If you're using LuaLaTeX, running \setmainfont{Tex Gyre Termes} shoud work.

Your test document doesn't actually contain en-dashes or em-dashes.

I suggest you employ a document setup that works equally under pdfLaTeX and LuaLaTeX.
The code used for the following screenshot loads the iftex package and performs different setup steps depending on whether or not pdfLaTeX is in use. In both cases, a Times Roman clone font is used.

\documentclass[letterpaper, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{xcolor, enumerate, sectsty}

\usepackage{iftex}
\ifpdftex % pdfLaTeX is in use
   %\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % that's the default nowadays
   \usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % Output encoding for non-ASCII characters
   %\usepackage[sc]{mathpazo} %% Palatino clone
   %\linespread{1.1} %% use only with Palatino 
   %%\usepackage{mathptmx} %% Times Roman clone; borderline obsolete
   \usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath} %% newer and better
\else % LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX is in use
   \usepackage{unicode-math}
   \setmainfont{TeX Gyre Termes} %% another Times Roman clone
   \setmathfont{TeX Gyre Termes Math}
\fi

\usepackage[skip=7pt, indent=1.5cm]{parskip}

\usepackage{microtype} 

\newcommand{\soptitle}{{\scshape%
  \huge Statement of Purpose\\[1ex]
  \normalsize Stanford University\\ Doctor of Musical Arts}
}
\newcommand{\yourname}{My name}
\newcommand{\youremail}{my\_email@gmail.com}

\usepackage{xurl}
\usepackage[bookmarks, colorlinks, %breaklinks,
      pdftitle ={\yourname --- \soptitle},
      pdfauthor={\yourname}, 
      %unicode % why??
     ]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{allcolors=magenta,
            urlcolor=named{WildStrawberry}}

\usepackage{lipsum} % filler text

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\soptitle

\vspace{4mm}
\Large \yourname \\ \youremail
\end{center}

\lipsum[1] % paragraph of filler text

\end{document}


Thanks, that seems to work. Is there some command, that make the font a bit more "boldish"? Or is it a font difference

@Cacilda - If you want a font that's darker -- not necessarily "boldish" -- than Times Roman, I suggest you employ Palatino rather than Times Roman. Specifically, you could load newpxtext and newpxmath under pdfLaTeX (not mathpazo, which is obsolete), or run \setmainfont{Tex Gyre Pagella} and \setmathfont{TeX Gyre Pagella Math} under LuaLaTeX. When using Palatino, do also run \linespread{1.05}.
